# wpf combobox data binding xml

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I want to display all groupnames (contact_grname) into my combobox, but only one item is showing up !
Why is that ?!

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="TeleData" XPath="/response/contacts/contact">

</XmlDataProvider>

<CollectionViewSource x:Key="TeleView"  Source="{StaticResource TeleData}" >
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="contact_name" Direction="Ascending" />

    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>

    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="contact_grname" />

    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TeleView}, XPath=contact_grname}" />
```

my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<response>
    <contacts>
        <contact>
            <contact_grname>group1</contact_grname>
            <contact_name>Bart</contact_name>
        </contact>
        <contact>
            <contact_grname>group1</contact_grname>
            <contact_name>Eric</contact_name>
        </contact>
        <contact>
            <contact_grname>group2</contact_grname>
            <contact_name>Mike</contact_name>
        </contact>
    </contacts>
</response>
```

Just group1 is showing up (one time).
When I use StaticResource TeleData instead of TeleView in combobox, then all groupnames are displayed (but there are doubles values because not grouped that way)

Expected output in combobox:

- group1
- group2

Now I have (with TeleView):

- group1

and if I use Teledata:

- group1
- group1
- group2

Comment: try using `/` instead ot `_`: <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TeleData}, XPath="/contact/name}" >

Comment: that is not the problem, typing mistake when I wrote it down here, I changed it

Comment: contact_grname I ment :-)

Comment: What is the output you expect to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display the `Groups` you can actually access the `CollectionViewSource.View.Groups` property via the `ItemSource` path

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TeleView}, Path=Groups}" SelectedValuePath="Name" />
```

Output:

- group1
- group2

Comment: Thanks for this ! Worked like a charm ! But when I use combobox.SelectedValue.ToString(), it shows MS.Internal.Data.CollectionView.... instead of the selected string :/ any ideas ? SelectedItem.ToString() is same result

Comment: You will have to add `SelectedValuePath` so you can get the correct value from `SelectedValue`, I have updated the answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much sa_ddam213 :D  worked perfectly ! Could you please take a look to my other post too ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052468/wpf-filter-with-combox-xml thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to your question, but it might help. Consider this ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="1">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data"
                             XPath="response/contacts">
                <x:XData>
                        <response>
                            <contacts>
                                <contact>
                                    <contact_grname>group1</contact_grname>
                                    <contact_name>Bart</contact_name>
                                    <contact_name>Eric</contact_name>
                                </contact>
                                <contact>
                                    <contact_grname>group2</contact_grname>
                                    <contact_name>Mike</contact_name>
                                </contact>
                            </contacts>
                        </response>
                </x:XData>
            </XmlDataProvider>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource Data}"
                     XPath="contact/contact_name"  />
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>
```

It shows "Bart", "Eric" and "Mike". With this binding:

```
<Binding Source="{StaticResource Data}"
                     XPath="contact/contact_grname"  />
```

You will get "group1","group2". But this is because I changed xml. With your xlm, I mean with this:

```
 <contact>
    <contact_grname>group1</contact_grname>
    <contact_name>Bart</contact_name>
 </contact> 
 <contact>
    <contact_grname>group1</contact_grname>
    <contact_name>Mike</contact_name>
 </contact>
```

the result is "group1","group1" and "group2".

So, One suggestion is to remove `/contact` from this line of code:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="TeleData" XPath="/response/contacts/contact">
```