# WPF filter with ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, filter

I'm new to WPF and I want to filter some data with `CollectionView` with my `ComboBox` control.

What I have done so far:

```xml
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="TeleView"  Source="{StaticResource TeleData}" Filter="Filter" >
<CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="contact_name" Direction="Ascending" />

</CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>

<CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="contact_grname" />

</CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
```

CS:

```cs
private int count = 0;
void Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{

    if (value == "" || value == null)
    {
        e.Accepted = true;
    }
    else
    {

        System.Xml.XmlElement ele = e.Item as System.Xml.XmlElement;
        string name = ele.SelectNodes("/response/contacts/contact/contact_grname")[count].InnerText;
        count += 1;
        //MessageBox.Show(name);

        if (name == "group1") e.Accepted = true;
        else e.Accepted = false;
    }
}
```

This code successfully filters all elements with the `group1` text within my `contact_grname` element.

But how to bind to my `ComboBox` which contains all `contact_grnames` (XML binded) ?!

```
private void cmbGroup_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    value = cmbGroup.SelectedValue.ToString();
    lblGroupName.Content = "Groupname: " + value;

    CollectionViewSource cvs = FindResource("TeleView") as CollectionViewSource;
}
```

Comment: Hey, so you want to populate another combobox with the items from the selected group in the other combobox?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to bind another combobox to the items that are in the group of the first combobox.

```
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="TeleData" XPath="/response/contacts/contact" Source="C:\Data.xml" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="TeleView" Source="{StaticResource TeleData}" >
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="contact_name" Direction="Ascending"  />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="contact_grname"   />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TeleView}, Path=Groups}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Name="comboGroups" />
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=comboGroups, Path=SelectedItem.Items}" DisplayMemberPath="contact_name" Name="comboNames" />
</StackPanel>
```

Result:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi ! thanks for reply ! No not with another combobox :-) I want to filter my datagrid with the item (contact_grname) that is selected in my combobox

Answer (score 0):

Once you select an item in your `ComboBox`, filter the elements you want to show, according to the item selected, calling the `Filter` method, passing to it the value selected in the `ComboBox`.

Then, refresh the datagrid, with:

`yourDataGrid.Items.Refresh();`.

and the CollectionView with:

```
yourCollectionView.Refresh();
```

Furthermore, have a look to the [this](http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html#filtering) article, explaining the features of a `CollectionView`.